# MySQL specific column addition

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
Bank_Account(Tran_Id, Pay_Id, Expense_Id, Amount, Balance) 
Payment(Pay_Id, Client_Id, Date_Payment, Amount) 
Expense(Expense_Id, Emp_Id, Amount, Expense)
```

In that `Tran_Id` is primary key for the `Bank_Account` and same for the `Pay_Id` for `Payment` and `Expense_Id` for the `Expense` as well. In the `Bank_Account` when `Pay_Id` is there `Expense_Id` is null and vice versa. Now I want to calculate the profit of company using `Bank_Account`. So how can I use the SQL script to calculate (the Sum of the `Pay_Id` based Amount - the sum of the `Expense_Id` based Amount).

Comment: Here Pay_Id and Expense_Id are foreign key for the Bank_Account.

Comment: This should be a simple JOIN along with `SUM` and `GROUP BY` to calculate the totals for each account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(p.Amount) as payments, SUM(e.Amount) as expenses,  
SUM(p.Amount) - SUM(e.Amount) as total_amount
FROM Bank_Account as b
LEFT JOIN Payment as p ON p.Pay_Id = b.Pay_Id
LEFT JOIN Expense as e ON e.Expense_Id = b.Expense_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should be your statement, but I think, you miss a field to group by in your `Bank_Account` table (i.e. company). 
You wants to know, the amount for a company, or?

```
SELECT <missingFieldCompany>, SUM(Payment.Amount) as Payments, SUM(Expense.Amount) as Expenses, SUM(Payment.Amount) - SUM(Expense.Amount) as Overall
FROM Bank_Account 
LEFT JOIN Payment ON Payment.Pay_Id = Bank_Account.Pay_Id
LEFT JOIN Expense ON Expense.Expense_Id = Bank_Account.Expense_Id
GROUP BY <missingFieldCompany>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    SUM(Amount * (Pay_Id IS NOT NULL)) AS PayIdAmt,
    SUM(Amount * (Expense_Id IS NOT NULL)) AS ExpenseIdAmt
FROM Bank_Account
```

Comment: This statement will sum up all payments and expenses in the both tables! I think, that's not expected!

Comment: actually i want to calculate the overall profit everytime which can be find using payment in - expense out....so i think ur answer is good but i need something different

Answer (score 0):

After trying more on it below query work for me .....

SELECT 
    (b2.total2 - b1.total1) as total 
from 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) as total1 from Bank_Account where Pay_Id is NULL)b1, (SELECT SUM(Amount) as total2 from Bank_Account where Pay_Id is NOT NULL)b2